# R Column Header Labeling based Horizontal values in second data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

With the following sample data,

```
Model <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3)
FactorID <- c  ("Factor1",      "Factor2",      "Factor4",      "Factor3",      "Factor5",      "Factor2",      "Factor3",      "Factor4",      "Factor1",      "Factor2",      "Factor3",      "Factor4",      "Factor1",      "Factor3",      "Factor2",      "Factor4",      "Factor5",      "Factor1")

FactorName<- c("SEK", "GBP",  "USD",  "CAD",  "YEN",  "GBP",  "USD",  "CAD",  "EUR",  "CAD",  "EUR",  "USD",  "GBP",  "YEN",  "CAD",  "EUR",  "USD",  "SEK")

a <- data.frame(Model,FactorID,FactorName)

Model <- c(2,1,3,4)
Factor1 <- c(0.054, 0.113,  0.903,  0.720)
Factor2 <- c(0.885, 0.153,  0.708,  0.750)
Factor3 <- c(0.430, 0.989,  0.518,  0.843)
Factor4 <- c(0.533, 0.6328, 0.343,  0.961)
Factor5 <- c("-",     0.055,  0.699,  "-") 

b <- data.frame(Model,Factor1,Factor2,Factor3,Factor4,Factor5)
```

I would like dataframe b to be split into 4 data frames (one for each model) and have the appropriate column header names (e.g., EUR, GBP etc instead of Factor1, Factor2 etc) which are found in data frame a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.  It splits both dfs by `Model` then loops through them, matching the columns of `a` to the column names of `b` and assigning the appropriate currency as the new name.

```
bSplit <- split(b,b$Model)
aSplit <- split(a,a$Model)

for(i in seq_along(bSplit)){
  names(bSplit[[i]])[-1] <- 
          as.character(aSplit[[i]]$FactorName)[
                match(names(bSplit[[i]])[-1],
                      aSplit[[i]]$FactorID)]
}

bSplit
$`1`
  Model   SEK   GBP   CAD    USD   YEN
2     1 0.113 0.153 0.989 0.6328 0.055

$`2`
  Model   EUR   GBP  USD   CAD NA
1     2 0.054 0.885 0.43 0.533  -

$`3`
  Model   SEK   CAD   YEN   EUR   USD
3     3 0.903 0.708 0.518 0.343 0.699

$`4`
  Model  GBP  CAD   EUR   USD NA
4     4 0.72 0.75 0.843 0.961  -
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way. I first rearranged the order of `FactorName` in `a` by converting `FactorID` and `FactorName` to character. Then, I split `b` by `Model`. In `lapply()`, I get `FactorName` for each `Model` and use them to rewrite column names.

```
library(dplyr)

arrange(a, Model, FactorID) %>%
mutate_all(funs(as.character(.))) ->a

split(b, f = b$Model) -> whatever

lapply(1:length(ana), function(x){

    foo <- a$FactorName[a$Model == x]
    names(whatever[[x]]) <- c("Model", foo)
    whatever[[x]]

})

#[[1]]
#  Model   SEK   GBP   CAD    USD   YEN
#2     1 0.113 0.153 0.989 0.6328 0.055
#
#[[2]]
#  Model   EUR   GBP  USD   CAD NA
#1     2 0.054 0.885 0.43 0.533  -
#
#[[3]]
#  Model   SEK   CAD   YEN   EUR   USD
#3     3 0.903 0.708 0.518 0.343 0.699
#
#[[4]]
#  Model  GBP  CAD   EUR   USD NA
#4     4 0.72 0.75 0.843 0.961  -
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,

I have come up with a solution for you, which follows:

```
library(stringr)
library(plyr)

models = vector("list", length(unique(b$Model)))

for (i in seq_along(1:(ncol(b) - 1))) {
    name <- paste0("model_",i,sep<-"")
    file <- subset(b ,Model == i)

    temp <- a[grep(file[,"Model"],a[,"Model"]) ,]

    for (col in colnames(file)[-1]) {
        colnames(file)[grep(col,colnames(file))] <- as.character(subset(temp,FactorID == col)[1,3])
    }

    models[[i]] = assign(name,file)
}

rm(i,col,temp,file)

models
```